# Is there a way to conditionally hide visualisations in Quicksight dependent on base size?

Tags: survey, amazon-quicksight

I would like to set up a conditional rule that hides a visualisation if the base size is less than 10.

Any help is much appreciated.

Under the format visual options there is a tab called Rules, although I cannot work out how I would use this to this ends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is official documentation describing the conditional rules in QuickSight https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/conditional-rules.html

The feature uses parameters which are like global variables that can be used across QuickSight analysis. Do you have parameters defined? Is "base size" a parameter or where does it come from? If you need to learn more about parameters, you can read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parameters-in-quicksight.html or look at workshop at https://catalog.workshops.aws/quicksight/en-US/author-workshop/3-add-interactivity/exercises